# Bochner's formula for fractional Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is there an analogue of the classical Bochner formula
$\frac{1}{2} \Delta |\nabla u|^2 = |\nabla^2 u|^2$ for harmonic functions that holds for $s$-harmonic functions?

Comment: The case of manifolds would also be interesting, when the classical Bochner formula also has a correction taking into account the Ricci curvature. In fact I realize now that I don't even know if PDE formulations (integral representations?) of fractional operators are well studied in manifolds (although the general theory of Lévy processes must cover this case, I presume)

Comment: According to Nicola Garofalo's *Fractional thoughts*, this is not known. See the end of Section 20 in [arXiv:1712.03347](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03347). This may have changed recently, though, as Nicola Garofalo ends this section with "We plan to come back to these questions in future works." :-)